# How to allow `www-data` to call `supervisorctl status`?

Tags: permissions, sudo, supervisord

I have a PHP script that calls `exec('supervisorctl status 2>&1', $output);`, which runs as `www-data` user (through Apache).

However this user does not have access to this command. I would like to allow permissions for `www-data` only for this exact `supervisorctl status` command. It outputs the running supervisor processes very nicely and I'd like to show that in my webinterface.

```
# Running `supervisorctl status` under any user except root:
$ supervisorctl status
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 13] Permission denied: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228
```

I've tried adding this part to the `/etc/sudoers` file (using `visudo`) but it results in the same error (I possibly need more permissions since the error refers to python?) :

```bsh
# /etc/sudoers
Cmnd_Alias SUPERVISOR_STATUS = /usr/bin/supervisorctl status

www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SUPERVISOR_STATUS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. Apparently, when defining stuff in `/etc/sudoers`, this means that you are going to call commands with `sudo`.

So in order to execute it in php, I'd run:

```
exec('sudo supervisorctl status 2>&1', $output);
```

This should then work under `www-data`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, non root users can execute supervisorctl command. The issue is with the socket permission.
You need to move supervisor.sock to an accessible path by www-data. e.g: /tmp/

Change file, chown and serverurl varibles in your /etc/supervisord.conf for this:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock       ;custom
chown=carlos:mygroup       ; socket file uid:gid owner

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
```

After that, restart supervisor and check the status to make sure everything is ok.

```
systemctl restart supervisord
systemctl status supervisord
```